# Борьба со спамом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот такая задача - борьба со спамом. Капча в форме взламывается, и кто-то обходит систему защиты обороны почтовых сообщений. Тогда я решил написать скрипт JQuery который фиксировал бы позицию движения мыши, и если данные движения зафиксированы, то тогда бы программный код разрешал бы послать сообщение. В случае роботовзлома, таких действий обычно не наблюдается в принципе.

Как считаете жизнеспособным такой способ защиты от спама?

И второй пункт. Есть код, связанный с обработкой window, однако почему перехвата нет в принципе. Что не так делаю?

```
  $(function(){
      var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-10, limitY = 150-10;

      $(window).mousemove(function(e){
          console.log('x - '+e.pageX+' y - '+e.pageY);  
      }   
 });
```

Comment: Это смотря что за взлом и нацелен ли он конкретно на вашу страницу. обнаружить скрипт и послать вам данные, как будто данный скрипт отрабатывал сложности не составляет. Может для начала заманить капчу. Например на гугловскую, автоматическую. Она в принципе такие действия то же делает. Только еще анализирует поведение пользователя на многих сайтах

Comment: Но если развивать данную тему и раз у вас некое почтовое сообщение, то я бы обратил внимание на ввод самого сообщения и заполнение других полей формы. Можно анализировать отдельные нажатия клавиш и то же включать эту информацию в данные о поведении пользователя на сайте. А вот потом предстоит самое интересное - на сервере проанализировать, что поведение конкретного пользователя похоже на человека и что оно боле менее уникально (для бота могут один раз записать все что происходило, сформировать для вас набор данных о действиях и посылать его один и тот же)

Comment: recaptcha v3 в помощь. Там как раз такие проверка на ботов идет на основе поведения на странице.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Не встречал такого способа, поэтому ничего сказать не могу.

**2)** Пример:

*jQuery*

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).mousemove((e) => {
    console.log("x - " + e.pageX + ", " + "y - " + e.pageY);
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*javascript*

```js
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    console.log("x - " + e.pageX + ", " + "y - " + e.pageY);
  });
})();
```